# Unity3D doen't see kazakh language letters

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new developer in Unity3D. When I write kazak language letter like ҚӨӘІҢ Unity shows ????? What I need to do? If I get data from json it will be shown correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom font and use that as the default font probably doesn't support those characters.